# "Put on the spot", origins of the phrase

Tags: phrase-origin

I was recently asked by my partner about the phrase "on the spot", with the meaning of suddenly being placed in a difficult or awkward situation. Both of us assumed that the origins of the phrase comes from theatre, relating to the spot light. Is this true or are the origins of the phrase different?

Comment: I don't know the origin, but my intuitions differ. Consider the other use of "on the spot" to mean *right then and there, immediately*, as in "He hired me on the spot." It's easy to imagine this phrase originating by the mental picture it draws: the thing happens without delay, without leaving. Thus, a little joke could arise when you force someone to be immediate: you *put* them on the spot, since the spot is where one is when they act immediately, without withdrawing for measured consideration.

Comment: Daniel, please provide your research for this question.

Comment: My guess is it all started with being *in a tight **corner*** (a likely losing position for a sword-fighter) >>> *in a tight **spot***  >>> ***on** the spot*.